# nvl with query inside

Tags: sql, oracle

Its possible to do something like this:

```
and zmt.mediatypeid in nvl(:P21_MEDIA, select mediatypeid from zbx.media_type)
```

:P21_MEDIA is a variable

Comment: Yes i have tried. My question is if is possible to do a query inside a nvl function like the example i put there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, you can use CASE statement to check the condition:

```
and 1 = CASE
         WHEN :P21_MEDIA IS NOT NULL THEN
            CASE 
               WHEN zmt.mediatypeid = :P21_MEDIA THEN 1
               ELSE 0
            END
         WHEN zmt.mediatypeid IN (select mediatypeid from zbx.media_type)  THEN 1
         ELSE 0
        END
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is called a [scalar subquery expression](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/expressions013.htm):

```
select x, (select y from another_table where foo = x) from the_table

select x from the_table where foo = (select y from another_table where bar = x)
```

It can only return a single column and a single row, anything else is an error.

I cannot test it right now, but I would assume you can also use it inside a function such as NVL. The documentation only mentions that it cannot be used in GROUP BY.

Comment: I don't think you can combine NVL and IN like that, though. It just returns a single value.

Comment: Yes your right it can't return more than one value, @schurik option with some changes is working.  Tanks for your help